# how to implement auto search in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam trying to build a auto search In angularjs. Iam able to get values in Json obj and loop through the list based on search., but when I give 'backspace' or delete the text and try to enter again., Old search results is appending to auto suggests. I dont get how to remove it from array. Please pind plunker below for code.

> code problematic section below.Here Iam getting different search results than which I supposed to get

```
for (var i=0 ; i < $scope.suggestionResults.length ; i++){  

            //if($scope.suggestionResults[i].title.indexOf(suggestText) > -1) 
            //if($scope.suggestionResults[i].title.match(suggestText))  
                var str = $scope.suggestionResults[i].title;
            if(str.indexOf(suggestText) > 0)    
                //$scope.suggestionResults[i].title.match(suggestText)          
                {  
                    output.push($scope.suggestionResults[i].title);  
                } else{
                    console.log(suggestText + 'Not matching');
                    //array.splice(index, 1);
                    if(output.length > 0){
                        output[i].splice($scope.suggestionResults[i].title, 1);
                    }

                }
            $scope.filterSearch = output;   
            console.log($scope.filterSearch);   


        // if ($scope.suggestionResults[i].title.includes(suggestText)) {
           // output.push(suggestText);
        // }
        // $scope.filterSearch = output;

    }
```

[Plnker code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6DgbrFkb8ZE4BhfileW?p=preview)

Comment: use `loadash`, it is easy to use

Comment: I have used filters insted and its working. Is there any possibility that filters start working after entering 3 characters `<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="values in suggestionResults | filter:searchText" ng-click="showProduct(searchText)">{{values.title}}</li>`

Comment: @shabarinath check my answer with the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare output as `[]` at the beginning so that you start with an empty array each time you type .. check the below code to remove the duplicate suggestions

```
$scope.autoComplete = function(suggestText){
        var output = [];
        if(suggestText.length === 0){
          output = [];          
        }
        if(suggestText.length > 2){
            $scope.hidethis = false;            
        }
                for (var i=0 ; i < $scope.suggestionResults.length ; i++){              
                    //if($scope.suggestionResults[i].title.indexOf(suggestText) > -1) 
                    //if($scope.suggestionResults[i].title.match(suggestText))  
                        var str = $scope.suggestionResults[i].title;
                        console.log(suggestText.toLowerCase());
                        console.log(str);
                    if(str.toLowerCase().indexOf(suggestText.toLowerCase()) > -1)   
                        //$scope.suggestionResults[i].title.match(suggestText)          
                        {  
                            output.push($scope.suggestionResults[i].title);  
                        } else{
                            console.log(suggestText + 'Not matching');
                            //array.splice(index, 1);
                            //if(output.length > 0){
                            //  output[i].splice($scope.suggestionResults[i].title, 1);
                            //}

                        }
                    $scope.filterSearch = output;   
                    console.log($scope.filterSearch);               
                  } 
}
```

Working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/oVRTRfC55lH5IuEIYukv?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working fine. Iam trying to make it search work after entering 2 characters. For that I tried using `if(searchText.length > 2)` and wrapped `for` loop inside it. But auto suggest stopped working. may i know where have i gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

Apply '**filter**' in '**ng-repeat**' as shown below

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="suggestionResult in suggestionResults | filter:{title:searchText}" ng-click="showProduct(searchText)">{{suggestionResult.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

It will give following results

> 1. For valid input it **will show suggestions**

[image]

[image]

> 2. For invalid input it **will not show suggestions**

[image]

[image]

Comment: ., I tried using the filter option as well u suggested. It works well when it can find product matching the tex., now if I search something which doesnt exist in product json list., it start showing all results and sometimes., unrelated keywords in results. Plunker here. pls check http://plnkr.co/edit/GjYxMVCfTBJZY3LGpIeN?p=preview ., over there., check json and just type., product in search box., it shows all results which is not matching any text in json.

Comment: @shabarinath I have tested for the link you have given and it is working fine here. I have updated my answer and attached some images. Please see those images. If you are still facing problem then let me know I will again look into that.

Comment: wow. That worked like charm. I wonder what makes the difference in `ng-repeat = `values in suggestionResults | filter:searchText"` and `ng-repeat="values in suggestionResults | filter:name: {{searchText}}""` .. since it reads ng-model value and reads through out the `li` elements., why the 2nd one filters more accurate